# What is the different between Navigation.PushModalAsync() andNavigation.PushAsync() In Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Reason for ask this i got error when i use PushAsync in xamarin forms mvvm architecture

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
```

Error is

[image]

I have corrected this error by changing PushAsync to PushModelAsync

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
```

anyone has idea about what cause to this error?

i am calling PushModelAsync from ViewModel

```
public class Page1Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
        public Command ContinueBtnClicked { get; }

        public Page1Model(INavigation navigation)
        {
            this.Navigation = navigation;
            this.ContinueBtnClicked = new Command(async () => await GotoPage2());
        }

        public async Task GotoPage2()
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `App.xaml.cs` wrap your first page in a `NavigationPage`, like this: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());`.

Now it will work. If you just have a single page, iOS doesn't know how to navigate to another page from there, so it needs a container page to handle navigation.

The reason the the modal variant works is because it spawns a new navigation stack and shows pages on top of everything else (hence modal).

Comment: Thanks for the sweet explanation. yes it works and got the knowledge